# KCL Node Analysis

Tags: dc, current-source, circuit-analysis

I can do mesh analysis with KVL no problem however trying to switch over and to KCL with Node analysis I cannot understand.

How do you determine current coming in to the node? I don't understand how to put currents in a equation/formula or how to tell what way their going through the node. I just don't understand it. The book literally sucks at explaining it. It's like i ran into a brick wall and have no idea what to do next.

I've attached a circuit that has been giving me trouble. If someone could please answer my question and explain how I would go about solving this circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Basically KCL says that the same amount of current entering a node must leave it. So for instance, if we label the R1/R3/5A as V1 and the R2/R3/3A as V2:

Node 1's equation can be described as:

\$ \dfrac{V1}{2} + \dfrac{V1 - V2}{8} = -5A \$

Node 2's equation can be given as:

\$ \dfrac{V2}{4} + \dfrac{V2 - V1}{8} = -3A \$

Rearranging, you have:

\$ \dfrac{5V1 - V2}{8} = (0.625 * V1) - (0.125 * V2) = -5A \$

and

\$ \dfrac{3V2 - V1}{8} = (0.375 * V2) - (0.125 * V1) = -3A \$

Solving the simultaneous equations gives us:

\$ V1 = -10.28V, V2 = -11.42V \$